# Upload bulk data into SQL Server 2008 from .csv

Tags: c#, asp.net, sqlbulkcopy

I want to let my users to upload 3000-4000 rows of data into SQL Server 2008. I would like to use `SqlBulkCopy`. What is the best policy to do it?

Option A:

- First the `.csv` file will be uploaded to the server and then `SqlBulkCopy` operation will be started.

Option B:

- Read `.csv` file from user's pc and then send that data to the server.

I am new to ASP.Net.

Thank you.

Comment: A would probably be the _fastest_. With B you'd have to send the data to the server using WebServices or some other mechanism which would probably be slower than SqlBulkCopy or [bcp](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms162802.aspx)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It really depends on your scenario and what you mean by 'fastest'. To "load" the data server side (meaning, option A, upload, then import) will almost certainly be faster on the server side. But you could also 'process' the data client side and launch an async uploader if the user experience is more important.

I would go with Option A just to keep the 'upload' decoupled from the 'import' process.

Comment: Welcome to SO, Roy.  Going forward, when you provide an answer, please try and provide some sort of code sample, to give the person asking the question an idea of what your thought process is.

Comment: There are quite a few ways to implement the solution. To me the question seemed to be a conceptual/design question. The implementation specifics (code) didn't seem relevant.